# Removing product from item-options in magento checkout cart

Tags: magento

Is it possible to show up the product separately in checkout/cart ,
I like to show up item-options added product separately, Is it possible in checkoout/cart ? 
Please check this screenshot : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxQWcg4HaqrsUEgwV2o1V09zUGs/edit?usp=drivesdk ,  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What added in the screenshot is a configurable product. I think what you are looking for is having 3 different line items in cart : 1)Actual Product 2) Plug 3) Cable

If you want to do so in 2 ways :

1) Override addAction in CartController.php and check if item is a configurable product. Load its simples and add them to cart instead of their parent configurable product.

2) Instead of having a configurable product, you can integrate a functionality something called freebie in which you will specify items you with the main product in backend. Override addAction in CartController.php and load the freeitems when their parent is added to cart. Add them to cart with the main product which will make different line item entries for all 3. Freebie functionality is not default in magento but you can get good modules for free in magentoconnect

Comment: Yep thats fine , will check with this once ,  So  if i have 6 dropdown in item-option in a product can i able to show up the each product separately in cart page .

Comment: yes, you will see 6 different products in cart page then.

Comment: Yep thats great , will try this, Can you just give me some reference for freebie functnality , i can't find exactly when i google it... Thanks ..

Comment: Actually there few extensions but you can only add one free item in it. What i will suggest is make it custom for flexibility. Create a product attribute called Freebie_Skus in which add comma separated free product skus you want to give with the actual product. This will be saved for the actual product in backend. In add to cart action, override it and load the freebie SKUS by easily fetching this attribute from product mode. Add these products to cart programatically. If you want to avoid admin errors, give a selection UI panel to select freebies in backend instead of manually putting skus